# Ensuring correct data in MS SQL Server, DB Level

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, validation, triggers

Say I have a table with the following layout:

```
Id  Int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
DateFrom datetime NOT NULL
DateTo datetime NOT NULL
UserId Int
```

UserId is a foreign key to a users table, and well obviously there's more data which is irrelevant to this question.

What I want to do, is to make sure that per User, there can not be any overlapping "periods", that is, say we have a row of data for User 1, from the 15th of May 2009 to the 18th of May 2009, then there cannot be any other rows in the database that contains any of those dates (15-18th of May 2009, both dates included).

How would I go about this in the best way? My initial thinking would be to use triggers, but I'm not exactly sure how and/or if there's a better way of doing some more "custom" data validation like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My friend I beleive you are spot on. Triggers are designed for this exact reason, to implement Business Rules.

The Books Online documentation has a few examples that will help to get you started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an INSERT/UPDATE trigger. Make sure when you write the trigger that it handles the case where more than one row is being inserted or updated at a time.

Comment: I am working on that at the moment, writing the INSERT trigger, while starting to think of ideas of how to handle the UPDATE one (seeing as it needs to run all it's checks on the final outcome) but I'm running into a dead end on the UPDATE trigger, any hints?

Answer (score 1):

A common problem. You can use constraints:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/03/08/storing-intervals-of-time-with-no-overlaps.aspx

Comment: This looked very good - the only issue here is that I cannot delete a row in the middle of a sequence - because there's a foreign key relation back to the table itself - I want to be able to do that.

Comment: On 2008, you can use MERGE.
Before that, you first move the row that you want to delete to the end, then delete.

Comment: I can see how potentially I would be able to use this, but as opposed to triggers this brings a few negative points:

1. The use of an extra column that is otherwise not needed.
2. Harder Insert, Update, Delete logic - would probably require use of stored procedures for all to be somewhat sane in the rest of my app, with triggers I can use regular statements (harder because stuff might need moved around).

All in all I want to be able to insert, update and delete rows in any order I want, I just don't want overlapping records in the table - triggers allows that and it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, especially if your granularity is at the day level (and by the way, if that is the case and you're SQL Server 2008, then you should probably use the date type instead of datetime), is to have another table like:
UserId int,
Day datetime,
Primary Key (UserId, Day)
And then insert, delete, update all the days for a user on any insert, delete, update in your original table and just let the server's uniqueness constraint on the PK do the validation for you.